# Table Spacing the cells

Tags: tables

Consider the table below and the result. I wish to increase the spacing inside the cells so that they are centered and spaced from the walls. I also wish to add border lines around the table.

```
\begin{table}
    \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{
    \begin{tabular}{l | c | c | c | c |  }
        Name & Estimator & Mean & Bias & Variance \\
        \hline \\
        Sample& $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i}(Y_i-\mu)^2$  & $\sigma^2$ & 0 & $\frac{2\sigma^4}{n}$ \\ 
        \hline \\
        Un-adjusted & $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i}(Y_i-\bar{Y})^2$  &$\frac{n-1}{n}$ $\sigma^2$ & $\frac{\sigma^2}{n}$ & $\frac{2\sigma^4}{n}$\\
        \hline \\
        Adjusted & $\frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i}(Y_i-\bar{Y})^2$  & $\sigma^2$ & 0 & $\frac{2\sigma^4}{n-1}$
    \end{tabular}}
    \caption{Comparison of Estimators}
\end{table}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using `\resizebox` to make the tabular material as wide as the text block is (and create a typographic calamity along the way!), I'd like to suggest that you (a) employ a `tabular*` environment, (b) get rid of all vertical lines, (c) use fewer but well-spaced horizontal lines, and (d) use display-style rather than inline-style math for the formulas.

The following screenshots show the effects of implementing these suggestions progressively.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{graphicx} % for \resizebox directive
\usepackage{array}    % for \newcolumntype directive
\newcolumntype{C}{>{$\displaystyle}c<{$}}
\usepackage{booktabs} % \toprule, \midrule, \bottomrule, \addlinespace
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht!]
    \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{
    \begin{tabular}{l | c | c | c | c |  }
    Name & Estimator & Mean & Bias & Variance \\
    \hline & & & &  \\
    Sample& $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i}(Y_i-\mu)^2$  & $\sigma^2$ & 0 & $\frac{2\sigma^4}{n}$ \\ 
    \hline & & & &  \\
    Un-adjusted & $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i}(Y_i-\bar{Y})^2$  &$\frac{n-1}{n}$ $\sigma^2$ & $\frac{\sigma^2}{n}$ & $\frac{2\sigma^4}{n}$\\
    \hline & & & &  \\
    Adjusted & $\frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i}(Y_i-\bar{Y})^2$  & $\sigma^2$ & 0 & $\frac{2\sigma^4}{n-1}$
\end{tabular}}
\caption{OP's table format with cont.\ vertical lines}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[h!]
\centering
    \begin{tabular}{l | c | c | c | c |  }
    Name & Estimator & Mean & Bias & Variance \\
    \hline
    Sample& $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i}(Y_i-\mu)^2$  & $\sigma^2$ & 0 & $\frac{2\sigma^4}{n}$ \\ 
    \hline
    Un-adjusted & $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i}(Y_i-\bar{Y})^2$  &$\frac{n-1}{n}$ $\sigma^2$ & $\frac{\sigma^2}{n}$ & $\frac{2\sigma^4}{n}$\\
    \hline
    Adjusted & $\frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i}(Y_i-\bar{Y})^2$  & $\sigma^2$ & 0 & $\frac{2\sigma^4}{n-1}$
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Without \texttt{\string\resizebox}, without all-blank lines}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[h!]
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt} % default: 6pt
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} lcccc }
    Name & Estimator & Mean & Bias & Variance \\
    \hline
    Sample& $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i}(Y_i-\mu)^2$  & $\sigma^2$ & 0 & $\frac{2\sigma^4}{n}$ \\ 
    \hline
    Un-adjusted & $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i}(Y_i-\bar{Y})^2$  &$\frac{n-1}{n}$ $\sigma^2$ & $\frac{\sigma^2}{n}$ & $\frac{2\sigma^4}{n}$\\
    \hline
    Adjusted & $\frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i}(Y_i-\bar{Y})^2$  & $\sigma^2$ & 0 & $\frac{2\sigma^4}{n-1}$
\end{tabular*}
\caption{With \texttt{tabular*} and no vertical rules}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[h!]
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt} % default: 6pt
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} lCCCC }
    %\toprule %optional
    Name & $Estimator$ & $Mean$ & $Bias$ & $Variance$ \\
    \midrule
    Sample& \frac{1}{n}\sum\nolimits_{i}(Y_i-\mu)^2  & \sigma^2 & 0 & \frac{2\sigma^4}{n} \\ 
    \addlinespace
    Un-adjusted & \frac{1}{n}\sum\nolimits_{i}(Y_i-\bar{Y})^2  &\frac{n-1}{n}\, \sigma^2 & \frac{\sigma^2}{n} & \frac{2\sigma^4}{n}\\
    \addlinespace
    Adjusted & \frac{1}{n-1}\sum\nolimits_{i}(Y_i-\bar{Y})^2  & \sigma^2 & 0 & \frac{2\sigma^4}{n-1}\\
    %\bottomrule % optional
\end{tabular*}
\caption{Fewer but well-spaced horizontal rules, display-style math mode}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Using the `nccmath` package (for medium size of fractions)  and `makecell` package for more vertical space around cells' contents. For "frame" around table you only need to ad `hline`before and after table body (see MWE below) and vertical line specifier `|` before first column and after last column.

Complete MWE is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nccmath}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
\setcellgapes{5pt}
\makegapedcells
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|l | c | c | c | c |  }\hline
        Name & Estimator & Mean & Bias & Variance \\
        \hline
        Sample& $\mfrac{1}{n}\sum_{i}(Y_i-\mu)^2$  & $\sigma^2$ & 0 & $\mfrac{2\sigma^4}{n}$ \\
        \hline
        Un-adjusted & $\mfrac{1}{n}\sum_{i}(Y_i-\bar{Y})^2$  & $\mfrac{n-1}{n}$ $\sigma^2$ & $\mfrac{\sigma^2}{n}$ & $\frac{2\sigma^4}{n}$   \\
        \hline
        Adjusted & $\mfrac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i}(Y_i-\bar{Y})^2$  & $\sigma^2$ & 0 & $\mfrac{2\sigma^4}{n-1}$    \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\caption{Comparison of Estimators}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

you can go for option1 or option 2

[image]

[image]

```
\begin{table}
    \setcellgapes{3pt}
    \makegapedcells
%   \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}
{
        \begin{tabular}{|l | c | c | c | c |  }\hline 
            Name & Estimator & Mean & Bias & Variance \\
            \hline
            Sample& $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i}(Y_i-\mu)^2$  & $\sigma^2$ & 0 & $\frac{2\sigma^4}{n}$ \\ 
            \hline 
            Un-adjusted & $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i}(Y_i-\bar{Y})^2$  &$\frac{n-1}{n}$ $\sigma^2$ & $\frac{\sigma^2}{n}$ & $\frac{2\sigma^4}{n}$\\
            \hline 
            Adjusted & $\frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i}(Y_i-\bar{Y})^2$  & $\sigma^2$ & 0 & $\frac{2\sigma^4}{n-1}$\\\hline
    \end{tabular}}
    \caption{Comparison of Estimators}
\end{table}

\begin{table}
    \begin{tabular}{l  c  c c c  }
        Name & Estimator & Mean & Bias & Variance \\
        \hline \\
        Sample& $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i}(Y_i-\mu)^2$  & $\sigma^2$ & 0 & $\frac{2\sigma^4}{n}$ \\ 
        \\
        Un-adjusted & $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i}(Y_i-\bar{Y})^2$  &$\frac{n-1}{n}$ $\sigma^2$ & $\frac{\sigma^2}{n}$ & $\frac{2\sigma^4}{n}$\\
        \\
        Adjusted & $\frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i}(Y_i-\bar{Y})^2$  & $\sigma^2$ & 0 & $\frac{2\sigma^4}{n-1}$
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Comparison of Estimators}
\end{table}
```